# Memory and upload size settings ignored in Macports php.ni

Tags: macports, php

I'm using Macports for PHP, and for some reason, all of the settings in my php.ini - at least the ones for memory_limit and upload_max_filesize - are being ignored.  For instance, I've tried increasing memory_limit to be > 128M, but it still remains at 128M.  I've also tried increasing post_max_sizeand upload_max_filesize, but no change there, either.  According to phpinfo(), the ini file being used is at /opt/local/etc/php5, and that's the one I'm editing.  I've made sure there are no other php.ini files that could be the ones read, and I've made sure to restart Apache whenever I make changes. I've run the "selfupdate" and "update outdated" commands, and I have the latest XCode, so I know I'm up to date.

Any ideas as to where those values are coming from and why I can't change them in php.ini?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved php.ini to /opt/local/var/db/php5, since that directory was listed under "Scan this dir for additional .ini files", and the values in there are being used now.  The thing is, there was no php.ini there before, and as I said, phpinfo() showed the one in /opt/local/etc/php5 as the one being used, even though changing the values had no effect.  Where were the values being used coming from?  Default PHP values?

Anyway, for now I'm happy, since I can make changes in php.ini that actually take effect now.